# How to extract specific fields of JSON Array in Java and store it in String

Tags: java, json

I have JSON data and want to extract data of only specific fields in Java and store it in String.
Example,
   From **issues**, key:651, From **project** name:test, **updated**, **created**  This details for all records of array issues.

Sample JSON Data:

```
"issues": [
        {
           "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
           "key": "651",
           "fields": {
                "project": {
                    "name": "test",
                    "Urls": {
                    "48x48": "https://test1.com",
                        "24x24": "https://test2.com"
                        },
                        },
                        "updated": "2019-03-05T13:24:56.000-0800",
                "created": "2019-03-05T13:24:56.000-0800",
                "status": {
                "description" : "";
                "name": "",
                }

            }
        },
                {
           "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
           "key": "321",
           "fields": {
                "project": {
                    "name": "test2",
                    "Urls": {
                    "48x48": "https://test1.com",
                    "24x24": "https://test2.com"
                    },
                },
                        "updated": "2019-03-05T13:24:56.000-0800",
                "created": "2019-03-05T13:24:56.000-0800",
                "status": {
                "description" : "";
                "name": "",
                }
            }
            }
    ]
```

Java code that I have tried so far jar used - (gson-2.8.5)

```
JsonObject object = (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader("C:\\MyData\\response.json"));
                JsonArray issues = (JsonArray) object.get("issues");
                JsonObject issues0 = (JsonObject) issues.get(0);
                JsonObject issues0data = (JsonObject) issues0.get("key");
                String issue_key = issues0data.get("issue_key").getAsString();
                System.out.println("Value of key is -> " + issue_key);  // java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject
```

**Updated Code**

```
JsonObject object = (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader("C:\\MyData\\response.json"));               
                JsonArray issues_data = (JsonArray) object.get("issues");



                for(int i=0; i<issues_data.size(); i++)  
                {
                JsonObject issues = (JsonObject) issues_data.get(i); 
                String issues_key = (String) issues.get("key").toString();
                String project_name = (String) issues.get("name").toString();  // returns null 

               }
```

Comment: why don't you deserialize it to POJO

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have added the code that I have tried. Getting error: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to string when you get the value.
Change your code like this see if it helps.

```
JsonObject object = (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader("C:\\MyData\\response.json"));
                JsonArray issues = (JsonArray) object.get("issues");
                JsonObject issues0 = (JsonObject) issues.get(0);
                String issue_key = (String) issues0.get("key");//<---here
                System.out.println("Value of key is -> " + issue_key);
```

**Update**

If you want all values just put it inside "for":

```
JsonObject object = (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader("C:\\MyData\\response.json"));
                JsonArray issues = (JsonArray) object.get("issues");
                for(int i=0; i<issues.size(); i++){
                    JsonObject issue = (JsonObject) issues.get(i);
                    String issue_key = (String) issue.get("key");
                    System.out.println("Value of key" + Integer.toString(i + 1) + " is -> " + issue_key);
                }
```

**Update 2**

The data "updated" and  "created" are not inside "issues" they are inside "fields" to get access to them you need to get them from "fields". You have to go inside level by level to get access to variables:

```
JsonObject object = (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader("C:\\MyData\\response.json"));
                JsonArray issues = (JsonArray) object.get("issues");
                for(int i=0; i<issues.size(); i++){
                    JsonObject issue = (JsonObject) issues.get(i);
                    String issue_key = (String) issue.get("key");
                    JsonObject fields = (JsonObject) issues.get("fields");
                    JsonObject project = (JsonObject) issues.get("project");
                    String project_name = (String) project.get("key");
                    String fields_updated = (String) fields.get("updated");
                    String fields_created = (String) fields.get("created");
                    System.out.println("Value of key" + Integer.toString(i + 1) + " is -> " + issue_key);
                }
```

Comment: Thanks, @Abbas Dehghan I have added the code that I have tried so far. I am getting error java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But just for reference can you please add previous code that you had shared.

Comment: previous code was for android java. i made a mistake. because you did not shared your code.

Comment: But currently its printing value for only 1 record from JSON Array issues I want it for all records

Comment: i hope this help you

Comment: There is one more issue I can only retrieve all data for key column of Json array **issues**. Cannot get data for name column which is nested inside fields->project. I have added updated code.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because you are casting a `JsonPrimitive` to `JsonObject`. So instead of using

```
JsonObject issues0data = (JsonObject) issues0.get("key");
```

you should do

```
String issues0data = issues0.get("key").getAsString();
System.out.println("Value of key is -> " + issues0data);
```

Here, calling `getAsString()` will invoke `JsonPrimitive.getAsString()` method. This will take care if the primitive is `boolean/number/string` and convert it to `string`.

Comment: Thanks! But now there is one more issue I can only retrieve all data for key column of Json array **issues**. Cannot get data for name column which is nested inside fields->project. I have added updated code.

Comment: You can use something like this to extract value of name field `issues0.get("fields").getAsJsonObject().get("project").getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString()`. Note: Do proper validation to avoid nullpointer exception

Comment: I am getting null pointer exception for some fields. Any idea of how to deal with this issue?

Comment: @VikasJ You will get this when `issues0.get("key")` is null and you call `getAsString()` on this. So do a check if `issues0.get("key")` is not null and then call the method `getAsString()`

Comment: Since I am using gson so tried this code for validation. Code doesn't fail with NULL exception anymore,but does not even write values if it exists in JSON for a particular field instead it simply goes in else block.  JsonObject object = (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader("C:\\MyData\\response.json"));   JsonArray issues = (JsonArray) object.get("issues");  JsonElement el = object.get("error") ; if (el != null && !el.isJsonNull()) { issue_type = (String) issues.get("fields").getAsJsonObject().get("issuetype").getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString(); else {S.O.P ("is null")}